# Is there a difference between LLVM attributes in the declare and in an attribute set

Tags: llvm

Compare the LLVM

```
declare "wasm-import-module"="hellowasi" "wasm-import-name"="reverse" void @reverse(i8*, i32, i8*)
```

and

```
declare void @reverse(i8*, i32, i8*) #1

attributes #1 = { "wasm-import-module"="hellowasi" "wasm-import-name"="reverse" }
```

Apart from being able to use `#1` attribute list on other functions, is there any difference between these 2 LLVM IR snippets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering myself.  The first adds attributes to the return value, while the second adds attributes to the function.  When adding attributes, LLVM can accept an "Index" where 0 means the return value, ~0 (the bitwise not of 0) is the function, and other values are the parameter number.